# Why won't ui.bootstrap load?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have my scripts listed like so;

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/myapp.js') }}"></script>
```

and then in my myapp.js;

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

I keep getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr].

Specifically;

Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.b...
    at Error (native)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js:24:186
    at b (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js:23:252)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js:23:495
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js:38:153
    at n (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js:38:1)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js:38:170
    at n (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js:7:355

What am I missing, the ui.directives declaration works on its own but the ui.bootstrap fails.

Pulled in ui-bootstrap 1.1.1 and cleaned up scripts like so,

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/ui-bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/myApp.js') }}"></script>
```

Error is gone.

Comment: that looks like a really old version ... try most current one as older ones won't be compatible with angular `1.4x`. Also remove bootstrap.js

Comment: Thanks charlitfl - really old version of what?

Comment: `ui.bootstrap` ... current is like 1.1.1

Comment: Try to add ui-bootstrap-[version].js and ui-bootstrap-tpls-[version].js as well. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages#build-files